# How to pass a list of elements into post method?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, attributes, freemarker

I dynamically add questions into a questionnaire. I need to pass my questions via a POST method in database.

My template:

```
<div class="questions mb-3" id="questions" model-attribute="questionsForm"> 
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

     $("#addQuestion").click(function () {
       var i = 1;
       $("#questions").append(
                        '<div id="q' + i + '" class="card border-info mb-3 mt-3" style="width: 40rem;" >\n' +
                        '<div class="card-body">\n' +
                          '<div class="form-inline mt-3">\n' +
                           '<input class="form-control col-sm-8 mr-2" type="text" name="tags">\n' +
                           '</div>\n' +
                          '</div>\n' +
                        '</div>');
                    i++;
                  });
                });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to send the questions on the request body of your POST method?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to send my questions on the request body

Answer (score 2):

You can do that natively (without any external libraries) with the [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API.

In order to send a POST request with the request body, you will need to store your questions in an array, and convert it into a JSON string using JSON.stringify().

Here is an implementation of the method with the POST request:

```
function sendData(questionsArr) {
  fetch('/some-endpoint', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(questionsArr)
  }).then(response => {
    return response.json();
  }).then(data => {
    // response
    console.log(data)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the questions in an array and pass the array in the body of the post request and handle it in your backend. If you want to know how to do a post request you could have a look into AJAX. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/